# Tool/library to find the differences between two versions of a javascript program

Tags: javascript, profiling, code-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I am working on a project which as a first step requires to find the differences between the 2 versions of a same program.
Basically, I should be able to parse the Javascript code into AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) and then find the difference between the two versions at the AST level.

Say for example, we have a javascript program:

v1.js

```
    function oddNo() {
      console.log('It is an odd number');
    }

    function evenNo() {
      console.log('It is an even number');
    }

    var n= 123;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
     evenNo();
    }
    else {
     oddNo();
    }
```

v2.js

```
    function oddNo() {
      console.log('It is not a even number');
    }

    function evenNo() {
      console.log('It is an even number');
    }

    var n= 123;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
     evenNo();
    }
    else {
     oddNo();
    }
```

In the above, v2.js has a change in oddNo() function.

So I need to find this difference as to which functions are modified in the next version and also some new functions could be added in the next version. I need to find the difference and get the modified methods.
Are there any existing libraries or tools to find this? If not any ideas on how to implement them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `diff` doesn't help you?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey:  diff tells you differences in source lines, not in program structure.  Check out http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer, which implements differences over ASTs in exactly the way OP requests.  Such edits are generally a lot more readable, because they explain code differences in terms of change to langauge constucts such as variables, expressions, statements, declarations, and actions such insert, replace, delete, copy and move.  Yes, there is one specifically for JavaScript.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Yes, I know what the OP is after. I was just curious if something more ubiquitous was not sufficient.

Comment: @Rkd:  did you find any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Any solution...?